# Bootstrap on asp.net button

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way that i can bind bootstrap onto asp controls?

Bootstrap button :

```
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></button>
```

Asp.net button:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"/>//How i add the span class? or is there a work around?
```

If this is not possible, is there a way that the html button can trigger of .net eventfunction?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something.
    }
```

I've tried adding onclick ="Button1_Click" on the html, it does not work.

Comment: Take a look at the `<asp:LinkButton>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `<asp:LinkButton>` to add your icon to the button. e.g.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="CogLinkButton" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-lg" runat="server" OnClick="CogLinkButton_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: clean and neat. Thanks.